# no module named cv2 on exporting anaconda path

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda

I have `ubuntu 14.04` in which I installed `OpenCV3` it works fine 
then I installed anaconda(python). To make it work it said that I have to edit **~/.bashrc** and export the anaconda path to it.

I changed to **python 2.7.8** and it gives an error: `no module named cv2 error..` and if I comment that line in **.bashrc** then python gets changed to 2.7.6 and the error disappears. What should I do ?

This is the error when I include the line in bashrc

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: /home/aman/anaconda/bin/../lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' `not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4)
```

Comment: The python installed by ubuntu and anaconda are different. Ubuntu comes with a pre-built version of python and when you install anaconda the packages will be different its best to build opencv from source with anaconda's python in it. Take a look here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/17536/install-opencv-for-anaconda-ipython/

Answer (score 0):

Try running `conda remove system`. This will remove the `libm.so.6` file from Anaconda. See https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/182